# Set up Linux user password expiration

Tags: linux, password

How do I set up password expiration policies for user accounts in Linux? Is it vastly different on each distribution?

In particular I use some Debian/Ubuntu servers, but links to appropriate info for other distros is obviously welcome.

[couldn't find a duplicate Q, but let me know]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I posted slightly quickly, it looks like both passwd and chage will work for what you would like to accomplish:

sudo chage [username] will interactively allow you to set things.  Otherwise here is the help output of chage and passwd.

chage --help output:
     chage --help
    Usage: chage [options] [LOGIN]

```
Options:
  -d, --lastday LAST_DAY        set last password change to LAST_DAY
  -E, --expiredate EXPIRE_DATE  set account expiration date to EXPIRE_DATE
  -h, --help                    display this help message and exit
  -I, --inactive INACTIVE       set password inactive after expiration
                                to INACTIVE
  -l, --list                    show account aging information
  -m, --mindays MIN_DAYS        set minimum number of days before password
                                change to MIN_DAYS
  -M, --maxdays MAX_DAYS        set maximim number of days before password
                                change to MAX_DAYS
  -W, --warndays WARN_DAYS      set expiration warning days to WARN_DAYS
```

Output from command passwd --help -

```
passwd --help
Usage: passwd [options] [LOGIN]

Options:
  -a, --all                     report password status on all accounts
  -d, --delete                  delete the password for the named account
  -e, --expire                  force expire the password for the named account
  -h, --help                    display this help message and exit
  -k, --keep-tokens             change password only if expired
  -i, --inactive INACTIVE       set password inactive after expiration
                                to INACTIVE
  -l, --lock                    lock the named account
  -n, --mindays MIN_DAYS        set minimum number of days before password
                                change to MIN_DAYS
  -q, --quiet                   quiet mode
  -r, --repository REPOSITORY   change password in REPOSITORY repository
  -S, --status                  report password status on the named account
  -u, --unlock                  unlock the named account
  -w, --warndays WARN_DAYS      set expiration warning days to WARN_DAYS
  -x, --maxdays MAX_DAYS        set maximim number of days before password
                                change to MAX_DAYS
```

Comment: A more in-depth ubuntu document on the topic:
https://help.ubuntu.com/9.04/serverguide/C/user-management.html

Answer (score 4):

You can set up expiration policies in **/etc/login.defs** - specifically PASS_MAX_DAYS=, PASS_MIN_DAYS= and PASS_WARN_AGE=

Also you need to edit **/etc/default/useradd** - INACTIVE= and EXPIRE=

It's not exactly the same situation, but there is more info here: [Expiring Inactive User Accounts](https://serverfault.com/questions/3682/expiring-inactive-user-accounts)